# Missing method '%' using has_many and find() in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-many

I'm getting a very odd error when I attempt to access the find method of a has_many relationship.

What am I doing wrong syntactically?

```
# Instructor model
class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

# Event model
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instructor
end

# Controller snip-it
i = Instructor.first
conditions = [ :start_time => params[:start]..params[:end], :submitted => true ]
@events = i.events.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)

# Error message
# NoMethodError (undefined method `%' for {:start_time=>"1283140800".."1286769600", :submitted=>true}:Hash):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
conditions = [ :start_time => params[:start]..params[:end], :submitted => true ]
```

Should read:

```
conditions = { :start_time => params[:start]..params[:end], :submitted => true }
```

You were creating an array with a hash in it instead of a single hash.